# Url.HttpRouteUrl with Attribute Routing and RoutePrefix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two Api Controllers:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Sql")]
public class SqlApiController : ApiController
{

    [Route("{serverName?}", Name = "OutageLastWeek")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOutageLastWeek(string serverName = "")
    {
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

And,

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Oracle")]
public class OracleApiController : ApiController
{

    [Route("{serverName?}", Name = "OutageLastWeek")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOutageLastWeek(string serverName = "")
    {
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

As you see, there are actions in the two controllers with the same route names. How can I call these actions using `Url.HttpRouteUrl`? How do I specify the route prefix?

The following doesn't give me the right url:

```
@Url.HttpRouteUrl("OutageLastWeek", new { serverName = "" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. In fact, you should be getting an error due to using the same name for two different routes. Each route name must be unique. There's no way around that.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped to find what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer helped to find what I was doing wrong.

The route name will not be part of the URL you use to call the Web API action. It's just a unique name that you can refer to when using `Url.HttpRouteUrl()` to create the URL for the route. So, my controllers should be like below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Sql")]
public class SqlApiController : ApiController
{

    [Route("OutageLastWeek/{serverName?}", Name = "SqlOutageLastWeek")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOutageLastWeek(string serverName = "")
    {
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

And,

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Oracle")]
public class OracleApiController : ApiController
{

    [Route("OutageLastWeek/{serverName?}", Name = "OracleOutageLastWeek")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetOutageLastWeek(string serverName = "")
    {
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

Then, I'll be able to generate the URLs like this:

```
@Url.HttpRouteUrl("SqlOutageLastWeek", new { serverName = "" })
@Url.HttpRouteUrl("OracleOutageLastWeek", new { serverName = "" })
```